# C# Repeat output at each click

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click

I'm working on a WPF project and I just want to repeat the result from a multiplication each time I click on a button.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double price;
    double commission;
    double result;
    price = double.Parse(TB_Price.Text);
    commission = double.Parse(TB_Commission.Text);
    result = commission * price;
    TB_Price.Text = price.ToString();
    TB_Result.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Example my first calculation is : 10*2 and "20" appears, then I do "10*3" and 30 appears but "20" still remains...

Sorry for my english. Hope my question is clear for you

TY

Comment: "30 appears but 20 still remains..."? Where does it remain? And what is `prix`? Did you intend to set `price`?

Comment: probably a typo: you declare a variable `price` but assign to `prix` which must obviously be declared elsewhere and is not later used for the computation.

Comment: Sorry my variables are in french so I just translated but forgot one. Fixed it.
@mm8  I just need to display all the results each time I click in the easiest way :
20
30
...

Answer (score 2):

You don't assign the `price` variable. Try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double price = double.Parse(TB_Price.Text);
    double commission = double.Parse(TB_Commission.Text);
    double result = result = commission * price;
    TB_Price.Text = price.ToString();
    TB_Result.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

You probably also want to to add some error handling to your code. There is for example a `double.TryParse` method that tries to parse a `string` to a `double` and return `false` it the conversion fails:

```
double price;
double.TryParse(TB_Price.Text, out price);
```